# Cómo corregir este problema para ejecutar success de Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy haciendo un sistema de archivos y en la parte de registro quiero usar *ajax* para recibir datos de que se ha guardado correctamente y que salte un *sweetalert* sin salir de la página:

Este es el código de la tabla de registro con el ajax

**register.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="frameworks/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center">REGISTRO USUARIO</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <form name="formRegister" id="formRegister" method="post" onsubmit="return addNewUser()">
            <label>NOMBRE</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control">
            <label>FECHA NACIMIENTO</label>
            <input type="text" name="fechaNacimiento" id="fechaNacimiento" class="form-control">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
            <label>NICKNAME</label>
            <input type="text" name="nickName" id="nickName" class="form-control">
            <label>PASSWORD</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-success">Login</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="frameworks/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="frameworks/sw/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function addNewUser() {
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          data: $('#formRegister').serialize(),
          url: "process/addNew.php",
          success: function(response) {
            response = response.trim();

            if (response == 1) {
              swal("ok");
            } else if (response == 2) {
              swal("user repetido");
            } else {
              swal("no ok");
            }
          }

        });
        return false;
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Este es el código donde se envia el POST con los datos de registro

**addNew.php**

```
<?php
require_once "../class/adduser.php";

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$fechaNacimiento = $_POST['fechaNacimiento'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$nickName = $_POST['nickName'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$datos = array($nombre, $fechaNacimiento, $email, $nickName, $password);

$usuario = new usuario();
echo $usuario->addusers($datos);
?>
```

Y este el código con la clase para añadir el usuario y cotejar si está repetido donde incluí un `return` si se cumplían las condiciones dadas que debe leer el **success** del *ajax* pero parece que no es así.

**adduser.php**

```
<?php
require_once "conexion.php";

/* clase usuario*/
class usuario extends conect
{
    public function addusers($datos)
    {
        $con = conect::conexion();

        //consulta para cotejar si el usuario exite
        $sql = "SELECT nick FROM t_user WHERE nick = '$datos[3]' ";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        if ($result['nick'] != "" || $result['nick'] = $nickName) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            // si no existe el usuario lo guarda
            $con = conect::conexion();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO t_user (name,
                                birth,
                                email,
                                nick,
                                password)

                                VALUES ($datos[0],
                                        $datos[1],
                                        $datos[2],
                                        $datos[3],
                                        $datos[4])";
            $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            if (isset($query))
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

El caso es que `adduser.php` no retorna los valores a `register.php` y por tanto no consigo hacer que el *sweetalert* salte.

El código es básico, lo se (estoy empezando) pero funciona. Graba usuarios nuevos y repetidos no. Espero que puedan ayudarme, he intentado otros métodos pero pasar datos entre php y js no es tan fácil como con ajax. Gracias de antemano.

---

Edito la pregunta para ser más conciso, necesito que esta parte del `success` que se encuentra en `register.php` (es el formulario registro)

```
success: function(response) {
  response = response.trim();

  if (response == 1) {
    swal("ok");
  } else if (response == 2) {
    sawl("user repetido");
  } else {
    swal("no ok");
  }
}
```

Reciba el `return` desde el método `adduser`que esta dentro de la clase  `usuario` en la hoja `adduser.php` y así forzar unas de las condiciones que hay en el `success` antes mencionado.

```
$sql = "SELECT nick FROM t_user WHERE nick = '$datos[3]' ";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if ($result['nick'] != "" || $result['nick'] = $nickName) {
    return 2;
}
```

Gracias de nuevo.

**conexion.php**

```
<?php

  class conect {
    public function conexion(){


         $serv = "localhost";
         $user = "root";
         $pass = "";
         $bbdd = "bluebox";


         $conex = mysqli_connect($serv, $user, $pass, $bbdd);

          if (!$conex)
          {
           die("connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
          }
          else{
           echo "connected successfully";
          }
           return($conex);
          }




      }



?>
```

para conectar con la bbdd.

Comment: Tu planteamiento es algo confuso. ¿Quieres pasar por Ajax para comunicar entre `adduser.php`  y `register.php`? ¿Entendí bien ese punto? Si es así, ¿por qué quieres pasar por Ajax? Ambos archivos están en el contexto del servidor, por tanto no necesitas pasar por Ajax, a no ser que algo cambie en el cliente y necesites ese nuevo dato.

Comment: Puede ser porque tienes un error en `sawl("user repetido")`...

Comment: Asi es @A.Cedano, cuando en 'adduser.php' se produce la consulta correctamente que se comunique con el ajax para ejecutar el success que serán swal con distintos mensajes, y la forma que he usado es un return 'valor'; lo he visto de hacer y no me funciona.

Comment: Pero, ¿por qué o para qué quieres pasar de `adduser.php` a `register.php` y por qué crees que en ese caso necesitas a Ajax como intermediario? Como dije antes, ambos archivos están en el servidor y puedes comunicar con ellos sin pasar por Ajax, a no ser que algo haya cambiado en el cliente (por ejemplo, después del *add*  el usuario cambió algo en un formulario) y necesites informar al servidor de ese cambio. Ese punto, que parece fundamental para resolver tu código, no queda claro. No sé si comprendes mi planteamiento.

Comment: @A.Cedano disculpa mi desconocimiento, intento lo que te he comentado, que cuando se realice la consulta en la bbdd retorne al success del ajax un valor determinado asi salte el emergente de sweetalert avisando de que se ha guardado o el usuario esta repetido, todo ello sin salir de 'register.php'. Si, comprendo tu planteamiento, pero no sé darle la solución.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es, en `register.php`, antes de insertar, verificar si existe o no y en base a eso, o registras, o mandas el mensaje de que está repetido.

Comment: Aparte de lo dicho por @FranciscoJavier, que debes corregir, ¿ya te has mirado la [sintaxis del sweetalert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)?  Porque diría que la has interpretado libremente como si de un **alert** se tratara y de ese modo no me extraña que no te funcione aunque consigas la respuesta desde PHP. ¿Y que es register.php?  ¿Como lo estás intentando llamar o enviar los datos?  No se ve en el codigo de tu pregunta (o no se verlo).

Comment: @masterguru, si se la sintaxis, es correcto, lo pruebo aisladamente y funciona; register.php es el formulario con el ajax; estoy intentando enviar los datos de vuelta con un return desde adduser.php; si lo estoy haciendo asi es xq lo he visto en otro codigo y funcionando y no se otra forma mas sencilla.

Comment: Parece que te falta un `preventDefault` en `register.php` para prevenir el envío del formulario, por lo que este es enviado, pero no devuelve nada al `ajax`...

Comment: @Netadri mis disculpas, no me di cuenta que estabas usando [este sweetalert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) en lugar del más usual que se usa ahora (indicado en mi otro enlace)

Comment: @Netadri por otro lado, tu register.php no contiene **nada** de código php, lo puedes renombrar tranquilamente a `.html` directamente sin más.

Comment: He editado el enunciado principal tratando de dar más detalle de lo que necesito que haga el código, mirad  al final del mismo, gracias de nuevo a todos.